# How can I integrate Watson Assistant with voice using Python API, including text to speech and speech to text?

Tags: chatbot, watson-assistant

Tried to integrate through Python API but it is not working. Even I want to have the microphone in the chat window.

I am not sure it is working as I have tried.

I expect it to work with the voice assistant. I have integrated the Watson assistant into the web using embedded code provided by the Watson assistant platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by utilizing the Watson python-sdk in your application. You can grab the text from Assistant and turn it into speech or grab the speech from a user and turn it into text for Assistant using functions such as `recognize` and `synthesize`. Code examples can be found in the docs linked below.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python